# How to view the ParsleyJS errors without blocking form submition

Tags: parsley.js

Is there a way to get the list of errors from parsley.js? I have a form that has one field that I want validate and give feedback to the user as a warning, but I don't want the error state for that field to block form submission. I am handling the form submission myself, so I'm looking for something like

```
$("form[name='client']").on('submit'), function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var form = $(this);

      form.parsley().validate();

      // pseudo code as I don't know how to do this yet with parsley
      var errors = form.parsley().errors().filter(function(err) { return err.field != field_to_ignore })

      if (errors.length ) {
         // error handling
      } else {
         // submit form
      }
});
```

Comment: You want to give feedback to the user? Why? And which feedback? Is it the parsley error message?

Comment: One of the error conditions is a warning more than it is an error; the user would be advised to fix the problem but is not obliged to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change the `inputs` or `excluded` options when you click on submit so that your inputs are all excluded.

Comment: Not sure it is what he was asking for. Excluded means that the submit will totally ignore the inputs, so he won't see (or handle) the error message anyway

Answer (score 0):

My Solution is to work with two validations:

1.The first one is binding the error to the UI.

2.The second one is after adding the `data-parsley-excluded=true` attribute to your field_to_be_ignore.

```
$("#myForm").on('submit'), function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    //the first validation bind the error message to the screen
    if (form.parsley().validate() == false) {
        $('myFieldToIgnore').attr('data-parsley-excluded','true');
        //Now let make a second validation:
        form.parsley().validate();
    }
    else {
        //submit
    }
});
```